# isObject error with @material/core package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, material-ui

When i try to run the project the console show me this error :
[isobject error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GefjB.png)

Then i checked the package-lock.json and i didn't find isobject dependency in @material-ui/core when i added to it manually the project work.

package-lock.json :

```
"@material-ui/core": {
      "version": "4.4.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@material-ui/core/-/core-4.4.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-Lz8sMFeCrtq5/pbhqClWFHpveL0huixjca0tw7uvh9xKKB7VyyYOyTu7RamSZLxb34UCSMPlobR+KK25Nqzkqw==",
      "requires": {
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.4",
        "@material-ui/styles": "^4.4.3",
        "@material-ui/system": "^4.4.3",
        "@material-ui/types": "^4.1.1",
        "@material-ui/utils": "^4.4.0",
        "@types/react-transition-group": "^4.2.0",
        "clsx": "^1.0.2",
        "convert-css-length": "^2.0.1",
        "deepmerge": "^4.0.0",
        "hoist-non-react-statics": "^3.2.1",
        "is-plain-object": "^3.0.0",
        "normalize-scroll-left": "^0.2.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.1",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "react-transition-group": "^4.3.0"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "deepmerge": {
          "version": "4.0.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/deepmerge/-/deepmerge-4.0.0.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-YZ1rOP5+kHor4hMAH+HRQnBQHg+wvS1un1hAOuIcxcBy0hzcUf6Jg2a1w65kpoOUnurOfZbERwjI1TfZxNjcww=="
        },
        "is-plain-object": {
          "version": "3.0.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/is-plain-object/-/is-plain-object-3.0.0.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-tZIpofR+P05k8Aocp7UI/2UTa9lTJSebCXpFFoR9aibpokDj/uXBsJ8luUu0tTVYKkMU6URDUuOfJZ7koewXvg==",
          "requires": {
            "isobject": "^4.0.0"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

package.json :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.2.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.2.1",
    }
```

How can i install a sub package for @material-ui/core in package.json ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved i installed the latest version of is-plain-object :

```
"is-plain-object": "^3.0.0"
```

I don't really understand what happen and why wasn't workin?